# What is simplest way to stream yammer Metrics data into relational database?

Tags: database, reporting, metrics, yammer

We start to integrate yammer metrics in our applications. We want to collect generated Metrics data into relational database table.

**How this Metrics data can be Streamed to database continuously ?**

I have searched the internet and found that Yammer provides inbuilt Reporter API(CSVReporter, GraphiteReporter etc.) which can Stream data to CSV, Graphite etc.

We cannot keep augmenting CSV or text files because they have to be archived from server after some time because of memory issues.

**Once yammer metrics API streams data out to some other place, do it keeps the copy of same in server memory ?**

We want to keep server memory free once data streamed out to database.

Answer (score 0):

The metrics stay in memory for a while in every situation, but you need a product like Ganglia or Graphite to store the data long term. These are normally better for operations metrics than a relational database and provide reporting add-ons. You'd need to have some extra code or extend the metrics library to log directly to a database.

Once the data is streamed out there is no point in holding onto it so it isn't going to affect your servers if you have it setup correctly.